# ReactJS href attribute of collapse can't take props value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, bootstrap-4, href, react-component

When I click the button inside of Collapse.js, the Card component must be shown. But it doesn't get 'props.href1' into href attribute. It gives this error:

Line 11:20:  Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected "..."
11 |      href="#"{this.props.href1}

This is App.JS

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import Collapse from "./components/Collapse";
import Card from "./components/Card";
import "./App.css";

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Collapse href1 = "cardhref" >
        <Card cardTitle="Barcelona" />
      </Collapse>
      <div className="card-group">
        <Card cardTitle="Man.City" />
        <Card cardTitle="Chelsea" />
        <Card
          cardTitle="Madrid"
          image="https://picsum.photos/id/237/200/300"
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.querySelector('#root')
);

export default App;
```

This is Collapse.js

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

const Collapse = (props) => {
  return (
    <div>
        {console.log(props.children)}
      <p>
        <a className="btn btn-primary"
          data-bs-toggle="collapse"
          href="#"{this.props.href1} 
          role="button"
          aria-expanded="false"
          aria-controls="collapseExample">
          Link with href
        </a>
        <button className="btn btn-primary"
          type="button"
          data-bs-toggle="collapse"
          data-bs-target={this.props.href1}
          aria-expanded="false"
          aria-controls="collapseExample">
          Button with data-bs-target
        </button>
      </p>
      <div className="collapse" id = {this.props.href1} >
        <div className="card card-body">
          {this.props.children}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
export default Collapse;
```

Comment: Change `href="#"{this.props.href1}` to `href={this.props.href1}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change to

```js
href={`#${props.href1}`}
```